# jQuery - Callback function

Tags: jquery, web-deployment

How can I allow a jQuery function to finish executing before a new page reloads?
Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#box1").click(function(){
    var div=$("#box1");  
    div.animate({left:'-=500px'},"slow").hide(1000, null);
    var div=$("#box2");  
    div.animate({left:'-=1000px'},"slow").hide(1000);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#box2").click(function(){
    var div=$("#box2");  
    div.animate({left:'+=500px'},"slow").hide(1000);
    var div=$("#box1");  
    div.animate({left:'+=1000px'},"slow").hide(1000);
  });
});
```

These two boxes are links to a new page and if the new pages load really quickly, the function is cut off.
Now, I know of the callback function that I can put in `hide()` but what can I make the function do, that won't affect anything?

EDIT:

```
<body>
    <a href = "Profile/profile.php">
    <div id = "box1" style = "background-color: #98bf21;" >
        <center>
            <div style= "border: 125px solid #98bf21; background-color: #98bf21;">
                Box1
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
    <a href = "KC_Choir/index.php">
    <div id = "Box2" style = "background-color: #98bf21;" >
        <center>
            <div style= "border: 125px solid #98bf21;">
                Box2
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Which new page? I don't get it

Comment: Have you tried using .load()  http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: why are you using 2 .ready() blocks? It is not a good practice, especially when you are dealing with the timing of the executions. Putting both click events into one .ready() help you on controlling the timing.

Comment: @roasted the two boxes are links in my html file.

Comment: @Edward Alright, thanks. But how can I make the functions finish execution before the new page loads?

Comment: @Edward AFAIK there's nothing wrong at all with two `.ready()` blocks - jQuery will run them both in sequence and there's no issues with timing.

Comment: you should show us how you reload the new page? This is the relevant code part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pqw8y/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#box1").click(function(){
    var div=$("#box1");  
    div.animate({left:'-=500px'},"slow").hide(1000,function(){
           window.location = this.href;
       });
    var div=$("#box2");  
    div.animate({left:'-=1000px'},"slow").hide(1000,function(){
           window.location = this.href;
       });
      return false;
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#box2").click(function(){
    var div=$("#box2");  
       div.animate({left:'+=500px'},"slow").hide(1000,function(){
           window.location = this.href;
       });
    var div=$("#box1");  
    div.animate({left:'+=1000px'},"slow").hide(1000,function(){
           window.location = this.href;
       });
       return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but `windows.location = this.href;` doesn't seem to be loading the new page. Am I supposed to replace `this.href`?